# static ip address changes automatically to 169.254.169.254 of cc machine (eucalyptus cloud)

Tags: eucalyptus

I am using  MANAGED-NOVLAN. I am using eucalyptus private cloud on centos 6.6 with one machine as CC and one machine as NC.
instance start fine, public/private ip addresses are assigned correctly,but my cc machines ip automatically change to 169.254.169.254 after starting eucalyptus cloud services(cc, cloud and nc).

configuration file for p4p1(on cc)-

```
ifcfg-p4p1:
DEVICE=p4p1
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=93a6bed5-6597-4e83-bcb5-0125e3b4dc6a
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.1.121
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=192.168.1.1
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME=p4p1
HWADDR=10:78:D2:54:8D:CE
```

Comment: looks like DHCP scope with no dhcp server...

Comment: how to stop static ip from changing to 169.254.169.254

Comment: i had installed cloud-init package and then removed using yum remove before this problem occurred

Answer (score 0):

The ip has not changed, but there are additional ip addresses.

You can list all the ip addresses for the device using:

```
# ip addr list dev p4p1
```

which would show that there are multiple ip addresses for that device and that these change when launching/terminating instances in your cloud.

Comment: ya true there are 192.168.1.120 and 169.254.169.254 ip addresses assigned to interface p4p1.

Comment: how to remove 169.254.169.254 and assign only single ip address as 192.168.1.120.

Answer (score 0):

After finding multiple ip addresses, you can delete one by using following command-

```
ip addr del 169.254.169.254/32 dev p4p1
```